# How to build a standalone AWS SDK .jar that includes all the dependencies

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services

We are trying to build a standalone .jar (.zip file) that includes all the dependencies based on aws-sdk-java-1.11.86 using maven command line.

The pom file for AWS is quite complex and we are concern changing it or writing or own since it might not be compatible with newer version of AWS.

Does somebody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The command is:

```
mvn package
```

The actual maven target is "aws-java-sdk-bundle".